# Integrate Ionic Sass Customization in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to integrate  Ionic Sass Customization in IBM Worklight hybrid mobile application. can any one help , Not sure what are the dependencies to make this work. Ionic is really cool in customization of themes in IONIC Mobile Apps.
http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/sass/
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because Worklight/MFP does not support the Cordova CLI and Ionic deeply integrates their CLI with the Cordova CLI, the approach I believe you should take is:

1. Create a skeleton app in Worklight Studio, integrated with Ionic. You can look at the [Starter Application](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/starter-application-samples/) (for MFP 6.3), that also has a version using Ionic.
2. Once you have that, you'll need to create an app purely with Ionic, and create the theme you like the most
3. Then you need to copy over the CSS files or their contents, whatever, to the Worklight/MFP project and manually integrate the two (references in the HEAD or the contents injected into the CSS files

Not a nice approach, but since there is no Worklight > Cordova CLI integrate, the process is not nice.

Comment: I believe we need gulp.js included in the project to make the Sass Customization in IBM Worklight  work. so do we need to just add that file in the project to make this work ??? thoughts ??

Comment: How about you try it?

Comment: Verify with a new application if it happens per my description above. If it happens then mention your OS. And plugin build number.